# VBA "Scientific" non-standard number format

Tags: vba, number-formatting

For reasons obscure (I need to match some formatting used in an ancient Fortran code) I need to output from Excel using VBA (to a text file) some numbers in non-standard scientific notation.

For example if x = 6000000

normal VBA:

```
  mystring = Format(x, "0.000E+00")
```

produces

```
  "6.000E+06"
```

I need a way of producing

```
  "0.600E+07"
```

instead.  I can't figure out a way of doing this using Format functions.  Is this possible?

Comment: `Format(x, ".000E+00")`

Comment: Note that `E+XXX` formats in Fortran are single precision (`Single`) and `D+XXX` are double precision (`Double`).

Comment: Can you show the _exact_ format specification in Fortran if the source code is available, or you just have outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Dim x As Double
    x = 6000000
Dim myString As String
myString = "0" & VBA.Format(x, ".0000E+00")
Debug.Print myString
```

Comment: `x` variable should be a floating type.

Comment: @JAlex thanks. I assume you mean `Double` in VBA terms.

Comment: @PGSystemTester, that did it! Yes, x is a double in VBA-speak

Comment: @SAL  -I am glad but be careful because  the  `E` notation in Fortran signifies single precision (`REAL`  type)  and so values beyond the 5th significant digit might start to deviate from VBA, unless you want to use `Single` internally. Also note that Excel cells store `Double` also.